# Laravel 4 Framework - Query scope not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im a big 'ol newbie at Laravel, and im trying to do a query scope but it doesnt seem to be working, i keep getting this error

```
Argument 1 passed to Letters::scopeForUser() must be an instance of User
```

My user IS logged in, but it still doesnt seem to be working.

This is my Letters model

```
<?php

class Letters extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'letters';

    public function scopeForUser(User $u)
    {

        return $query->where('userid', '=', $u->id);

    }

}
```

and in my controller i have the following

```
Route::get('myletters', array(
    'before' => 'auth|userdetail',
    function()
    {

        // Grab the letters, if any, for this user
        $letters = Letters::forUser(Auth::user())->get();

        $data = [
            'letters' => $letters
        ];

        return View::make('myletters', $data);

    }
));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a variable `$query` as the first argument to your method in the Model. For example:

```
public function scopeForUser($query, User $u)
{

    return $query->where('userid', '=', $u->id);

}
```

The first argument doesn't necessarily need to be `$query`, but it should be the same variable that you are using inside the scope method (`$query` in this case).